# URL rewriting for static files in ASP.NET core 3 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite extension

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an issue with URL rewriting in asp.net core 3 using static files. 
So I want to rid of .html extension in URL.

My launchSettings.json looks like this:

```
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "DemoSignUp.html",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

So to rewrite it to "DemoSignUp" I added these lines of code in my Startup.cs:

```
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("DemoSignUp.html", "DemoSignUp")
            .AddRewrite("DemoSignUp", "DemoSignUp.html", skipRemainingRules: false));
```

But my URL still have .html extension

```
https://localhost:44319/DemoSignUp.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the rewriter middleware before the static files middleware like:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("DemoSignUp.html", "DemoSignUp")
            .AddRewrite("DemoSignUp", "DemoSignUp.html", skipRemainingRules: false));
app.UseStaticFiles();//after above rewriter rules

app.UseRouting();

//other middlewares
```

Comment: However, on the front side, after rewriting, some( Not all, for example, images, are working fine and some other css and js files too) of my css and js files had been loaded successfully but don't work at all, like they haven't been loaded. I got  uncaught syntax error: unexpected token '> ' at <doctype html> line. and in response headers for these files i got content-type : "text/html" instead of "application/javascript". Do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: @Roma have absolutely the same issue. When requesting js-files the response is always `index.html`. Do you solve this problem?